# Array passed as prop doesn't reflect changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, immutability, react-props

This question is more for understanding more how react handles and reacts to changes, than implementation, therefore I'm letting immutable-props-apprach go for a little bit.

I'm trying to get the first element of an array and remove it from the original array, which was passed to component as a prop:

```
const ChildComponent = (
  arrayToChange: Array<any>[]
) => {
  const elementFromArray = arrayToChange.shift();
}
```

From the [definition of the shift() method:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element. This method changes the length of the array.

Even though the elementFromArray variable now contains the element from array, the array is intact, it was not affected in any way and still contains all the elements.

But how is that possible? React should pass the props by reference, therefore the original array should be affected. I'd understand if React had some protective measures in place and the changes wouldn't be reflected in the parent, however, I'd still expect changes being reflected in the child.
I cannot find anything useful which would explaing this behaviour, majority of the resources only mention the immutable approach to props and how to find a way around it, not the reasons or logic behind it.

Even though the elementFromArray variable now contains the element from array, the array is intact, it was not affected in any way and still contains all the elements. However, if I use push() method, then the changes are reflected, arrayToChange contains one more element.

My question then is - why does the arrayToChange react differently to these methods? If shift() doesn't change the contents, I'd expect push() wouldn't either.

Comment: React is not reactive, so it doesn't handle those changes. Just if the component will be rendered (while props are changed or the parent component is rendered) updated list length will be taken

Comment: To be sure, what you are saying is that you pass in the array then attempt to mutate it by calling shift, but the 'ellementFromArray' is not mutating?  how are you printing it out to verify that?

Comment: but I don't understand the difference between using, for example, push() method, which affects the length of the array and the changes are reflected when rendering, however, shift() doesn't affect the length, the element just stays there

Comment: @terpinmd - I'm not printing the result, I'm actually rendering components based on the information inside the array using map().. I tried printing it out through JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) "hack" before and after calling shift() method and the result is the same

Comment: Im still not totally tracking, but in the case of an array you would need to change the reference not the data in the object to get a re-render.  shifting it while changing the data isnt changing equality meaning the reference, as you pointed out, is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what this question is but I am going on a limb here to take a guess at it so please comment here and I will change before downvoting.

I think you should try this, in your child component:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState(arrayToChange);

React.useEffect(() => setData(arrayToChange), [arrayToChange.length]);
```

Then use "data" to map through to output in your jsx

Then in your parent component, do the shift on the arrayToChange.  You can think of the useEffect as a "watcher" which will fire when the length of the array changes.

Comment: I'm actually not trying to solve the issue, I took a different approach to avoid mutating the prop in the end, I just got back to this because I cannot wrap my mind around why shift() method doesn't change the content of the array, but other methods do - eg push().. if I pass 3 elements to child, I apply shift() method in the child component and then go to rendering part, why do I still render 3 elements, instead of 2?

Comment: I think the above snippet will still be your friend.  Instead of logging, you can set the state. Ill try one more edit to the post, hopefully it will help

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Parent() {
  const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
  const [letters] = React.useState(["a", "b", "c"]);

  return (
    <div className="bg-yellow">
      A: {JSON.stringify(letters)}
      <ChildShowArray array={letters} />
      B: {JSON.stringify(letters)}
      <ChildChangeArray arrayToChange={letters} />
      C: {JSON.stringify(letters)}
      <ChildShowArray array={letters} />
      D: {JSON.stringify(letters)}

      <hr />
      <button type="button" onClick={forceUpdate}>re-render</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildChangeArray({ arrayToChange }) {
  const elementFromArray = arrayToChange.shift();
  
  return (
    <div className="bg-red">
      elementFromArray = {JSON.stringify(elementFromArray)}
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildShowArray({ array }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg-green">
      array = {JSON.stringify(array)}
    </div>
  );
}

// helper hook
function useForceUpdate() {
  const [_state, setState] = React.useState({});
  return React.useCallback(() => { setState({}) }, []);
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<Parent />)
```

```css
.bg-yellow { background: yellow }
.bg-red { background: red }
.bg-green { background: green }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The behaviour in the snippet can be explained if you see the rendering process as a breadth-first algorithm.

JSX will convert:

```
<div className="bg-yellow">
  A: {JSON.stringify(letters)}
  <ChildShowArray array={letters} />
  B: {JSON.stringify(letters)}
  <ChildChangeArray arrayToChange={letters} />
  C: {JSON.stringify(letters)}
  <ChildShowArray array={letters} />
  D: {JSON.stringify(letters)}
</div>
```

Into the following JavaScript:

```js
React.createElement("div", { className: "bg-yellow" },
  "A: ", JSON.stringify(letters),
  React.createElement(ChildShowArray, { array: letters }),
  "B: ", JSON.stringify(letters),
  React.createElement(ChildChangeArray, { arrayToChange: letters }),
  "C: ", JSON.stringify(letters),
  React.createElement(ChildShowArray, { array: letters }),
  "D: ", JSON.stringify(letters),
)
```

`React.createElement(ChildShowArray, { array: letters })` creates a structure that does not immediately invoke the `ChildShowArray` component. It will create some sort of intermediate structure/object that only runs whenever the renderer asks it to run.

JavaScript placed within `{...}` (JSX context) are passed directly as arguments, and therefore are resolved directly. Meaning that all `{JSON.stringify(letters)}` inside `Parent` runs before any of the code in child components runs.

When building the parent structure is complete, the renderer will visit each intermediate structure/object and asks it to render. This is done from top to bottom, which is why the first `ChildShowArray` render does still show the full array. Then `ChildChangeArray` is rendered which removes the first element. The second `ChildShowArray` render reflects this change, and is rendered without the first element.

Note that `shift()` does change the contents of `letters`, but when it's called the content of `Parent` is already rendered and no longer changes. This change does impact `Parent` on the next render (click "re-render" button in snippet). It also impacts renders of other child components below it that use the same array reference.